# sp_playlist_create returns NULL second time

Tags: libspotify

I am using `sp_playlist *sp_playlist_create(sp_session *sess, sp_link *link)` to load playlists from a *sp_link that I create using `sp_link *sp_link_create_from_string(char *uri)`.

I am doing this twice, using equal uris, and the first time it works perfectly but the second time I get a `NULL` from `sp_playlist_create`.

This only happens with anonymized playlists such as `spotify:user:@fa4bb01873c9bc2e71c72a4d956c8184:playlist:56P21bVHLnRHna9HL3cDG6`, not with playlists belonging to known users such as `spotify:user:zond:playlist:5myg4jcx2TgJwFdV9wSV5e`.

Is this a bug in libspotify, or could it be my bad?